# Using CTE how to get the parent and child data alternatively in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm using the AdventureWorks2008R2 sample database.

Here my theme is to get in

- First Row: want get data of Salesman id
- Next row : with the Customers id related to Salesman id
- and it should alternate PARENT AND CHILD datas.

***Note**: but my stored procedure return the whole parent data first, followed by whole child data

My desired sample output should be like this

- `274,276,284` are parent data rows, rows immediately below the parent rows are the child rows

Sample:

```
SalesPersonID     PostalCode     City       
------------------------------------------
274                98027        Issaquah        
43849             SO43849         NULL      
44082             SO44082        NULL       
276                98027        Issaquah        
43663             SO43663         NULL      
43666             SO43666         NULL      
43859             SO43859         NULL      
284                98055         Renton     
47982             SO47982         NULL      
47992             SO47992         NULL      
47998             SO47998         NULL
```

My stored procedure is:

```
Create proc sales1  
as begin 
    set nocount on 

    declare @SalesPersonID int 

    create table #table 
    (
        id int identity(1,1) primary key clustered,
        SalesPersonID int
    )

    create table #table1
    ( 
        SalesPersonID int null , 
        PostalCode nvarchar (15) null,City varchar (30) null 
    ) 

    insert into #table 
       select distinct  
          SA.BusinessEntityID 
       from 
          Sales.SalesPerson SA 
       join 
          Sales.SalesOrderHeader S on S.SalesPersonID = SA.BusinessEntityID   
                                   and S.SalesPersonID is not null

    ;with CTE as  
    (
       select distinct 
           s.SalesPersonID,
           cast(A.PostalCode as nvarchar(25)) as PostalCode,
           A.City   
       from             
           Sales.SalesOrderHeader S(NOLOCK),  
           Person.Person P (NOLOCK),
           Person.Address A (NOLOCK),
           #table t   
       where 
           s.SalesPersonID is not null
           and S.SalesPersonID = P.BusinessEntityID
           and S.SalesPersonID = A.AddressID
           and S.SalesPersonID in ('274', '276')

       union all  

       select  
           a.SalesOrderID,
           a.SalesOrderNumber,
           null  
       from 
           CTE C  
       inner join 
           Sales.SalesOrderHeader A (NOLOCK) on A.SalesPersonID = C.SalesPersonID   
    ) 
    select * 
    from cte   

    set nocount off  
end
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to implement a column just for sorting, I would use `SalesPersonID` to do concatenation and sorting:

```
;WITH CTE
AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT s.SalesPersonID
        , CAST(A.PostalCode AS NVARCHAR(25)) AS PostalCode
        , A.City
        , CAST(s.SalesPersonID AS VARCHAR(MAX)) AS SortOrder    -- Here
    FROM Sales.SalesOrderHeader S(NOLOCK)
        , Person.Person P(NOLOCK)
        , Person.Address A(NOLOCK)
        , #table t
    WHERE s.SalesPersonID IS NOT NULL
        AND S.SalesPersonID = P.BusinessEntityID
        AND S.SalesPersonID = A.AddressID
        AND S.SalesPersonID IN ('274', '276')

    UNION ALL

    SELECT a.SalesOrderID
        , a.SalesOrderNumber
        , NULL
        , C.SortOrder + CAST(a.SalesPersonID AS VARCHAR(MAX))   -- And here
    FROM CTE C
    INNER JOIN Sales.SalesOrderHeader A(NOLOCK)
        ON A.SalesPersonID = C.SalesPersonID
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte
ORDER BY SortOrder;
```

There might be some typo in modified code, but this should work for you.

Comment: How the sort order will be in case of adding another Recursive query? @Evaldas Buinauskas

Comment: @KavinChakaravarthi Well, best answer is that it depends on your query. ;) By the way, in my answer there's a typo: `C.SortOrder + CAST(a.SalesPersonID AS VARCHAR(MAX))` should be `C.SortOrder + CAST(a.SalesOrderIDAS VARCHAR(MAX))`

Comment: Can i have ur gtalk id.i have some clarifications...PLz share